# RaphaelJS image clip-rect not working

Tags: raphael

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/7f2ez/4/) I have a Raphael canvas with two images. The first one is the complete image (not clipped) and the second one is the same image but clipped. For some reason the second image is not showing up. What's wrong with this code?

javascript:

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'));

var img = paper.image('http://designsbynickthegeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/social-header.png', 0, 0, 480, 259 );

var img2 = paper.image('http://designsbynickthegeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/social-header.png', 0, 300, 40, 40 );

img2.attr({'clip-rect': "0,0,40,40" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes.

*First*: You scaled your image down. Change

```
var img2 = paper.image('http://designsbynickthegeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/social-header.png', 
                        0, 300, 40, 40 );
```

to

```
var img2 = paper.image('http://designsbynickthegeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/social-header.png', 
                        0, 300, 480, 259 );
```

*Second*: You used the wrong clipping coordinates. Change

```
img2.attr({'clip-rect': "0,0,40,40" });
```

to

```
img2.attr({'clip-rect': "0,300,40,40" });
```

see your edited fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7f2ez/5/).